# Spark AR: emit an event on certain value

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming

I am new to Spark AR and trying to start an animation from canvas top to bottom. However, canvas height is 0 at start. It only becomes activated a moment later. So, I suppose I need to emit certain event when `canvas.bounds.height > 0`, and subscribe a function to it. But how?

Comment: Maybe my actual problem is to be able to convert a signal into a primitive value. The thing is that canvas.bounds.height.pinLastValue() turns out to be zero, although Diagnostics.watch('', canvas.bounds.height) shows a non-zero value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
canvas.bounds.height.gt(0).monitor().subscribe(e=>{
  if(e.newValue){
    //canvas height is greater than 0, do stuff...
  }
});
```

Bounds.height is a ScalarSignal type, which supports a huge variety of different types of event listeners. See the documentation page here for more info: https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/developer/reference/classes/ReactiveModule.ScalarSignal

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The subscribed event never fires. I had also tried the same line without the `gt(0) ` condition, which I suppose should do the same, but with no success.